# useParams() is an empty object in react-router-dom v6.8

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am simply trying to retrieve the params from a dynamic route (`"/articles/:articleId"`) in React using `react-router-dom` v 6.8

```json
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",    
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
```

I tried to follow [the Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params), but I must be missing something here.

App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"/articles/:articleId"} element={Article()}/>
        <Route path={"/articles"} element={Articles()}/>
        <Route path={"/404"} element={NotFoundPage()}/>
        <Route path={"/"} element={HomePage()}/>
        <Route path={"*"} element={NotFoundPage()}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Article.tsx

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Article = () => {
  const { articleId } = useParams()
  const params = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('even inside useEffect', params);
  }, [])
    
  console.log("Article  ", useParams(), articleId)

  return (
    <div>ID: {articleId}</div>
  )
}

export default Article
```

Output
[image: unexpected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. You are directly calling the React functions instead of rendering them as JSX. The components aren't called as part of the normal React component lifecycle, so the params are not populated.
2. `react-router-dom@6` is written entirely in Typescript, so there is no need for any external typings, especially those from `react-router-dom@5` which will be woefully incorrect for RRDv6.

The `Route` component's `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, value.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/articles/:articleId" element={<Article />} />
        <Route path="/articles" element={<Articles />} />
        <Route path="/404" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Uninstall the unnecessary dependency.

```
npm uninstall --save @types/react-router-dom
```